# How to send AJAX/Jquery object to Controller (discrepancy) MVC4

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have had this confusion for a while and it's because of the following reason:

I am trying to send a jquery object

```
var myObject = {
                    Title: $('#Title').val(),
                    Title2: $('#Title2').val(),
                    Title3: $('#Title3').val(),
                };
```

through an ajax call

```
                    $.ajax({
                    data: { myObjectName = myObject
                    },
                    datatype: "json",
                    url: "myUrl",
                    cache: false,
                    error: function (ts)
                    {//handle error},
                    success: function (result)
                    {//handle success}
                });
```

I'm receiving my object in my controller like this:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(ObjectType myObjectName)
```

However, when receiving the object from javascript, it does not recognize it as such and just instantiates a new ObjectType.

I know I can send it as a string, serialize it if I put my object inside a form, etc...what I want to know is why this approach seems to work for me sometimes (I have gotten it to work with other ObjectType(s)) and in other instances it doesn't. Does it have anything to do with how complex the object is? Sending an incomplete object? (The latter one doesn't seem to be it since I have sent 'incomplete' objects and the empty fields just get instantiated with null)

ANY insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to;

```
$.ajax({
    data: myObject,
    datatype: "application/json",
    type: "POST",
    url: "myUrl",
    cache: false,
    error: function (ts)
    {//handle error},
    success: function (result)
    {//handle success}
});
```

Notice that the type is a POST which means you will also need to add `[HttpPost]` to your ActioResult.

As long as `ObjectType` is a class with the fields

```
public class ObjectType
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Title2 { get; set; }
    public string Title3 { get; set; }
}
```

Your current code is attempting to bind your model to something which would resemble

```
public class SomeObject
{
    ObjectType myObjectName { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectType{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Title2 { get; set; }
    public string Title3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I made a pending edit-- you must pass `type: "POST"` as a part of your settings to the $.ajax call.  If you don't, it defaults to "GET", which MVC doesn't allow in some (most?) cases. I also changed the datatype to "application/json"

Comment: @ps2goat Good shout. missed that. Thanks.

Comment: That did it!!! AMAZING! Thank you! I understand a bit better, the parameters being passed have nothing to do with the controller(?), it's the request and the data being appended to that request(?) :)  
1 more thing, what if I want to pass a second parameter, say a string

Comment: `data: {myobject, parametername: newParameter}`, where 'parametername' is the name of your parameter in the web method, and 'newParameter' is your javascript string variable.

Comment: To add an extra parameter I think it would be `{ myObjectName: myObject, stringParameter: 'hello world' }` and the ActionResult would expect `(ObjectType myObjectName, string stringParameter)`

Comment: That's where my problem lies! Whenever sending one item (string or object) it receives it just fine. But when sending 2 or more, I run into this problem.  The myObjectName is instantiated with the new attribute and not reading the values from my ajax call :(

Comment: If I have no other choice I'll stringify my object and send it as thus, but I refuse to believe it CAN'T be done the way I have exposed it in this question. But of course, I could be wrong